Issue with Playwright Browser in Electron-Vue3 Build Using Electron-Builder
I'm working on an Electron-Vue3 application that uses Playwright for web scraping. Everything works fine during development, but after I build the installer with electron-builder, the browser stops functioning.
The only solution I've found is to explicitly define the browser's executablePath pointing to a local directory. However, when I try to make the path relative to the app (by including the browser within the app itself), it fails to work after installation.
What I'm looking for:
Is there a way to include the Chrome browser inside the installer/compiled app (like within the /resources directory) and configure Playwright to use that browser from within the installed app?
Addiocional Context:
package.json
{
  "name": "playpix-brayo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "playpix",
  "main": "main/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node scripts/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js && electron-builder --config.extraMetadata.main=main/main.js --config.extraMetadata.buildDependencies.node-abi=108",
    "build:win": "node scripts/build.js && electron-builder --win --config.extraMetadata.main=main/main.js --config.extraMetadata.buildDependencies.node-abi=108",
    "build:mac": "node scripts/build.js && electron-builder --mac",
    "build:linux": "node scripts/build.js && electron-builder --linux"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/deluze/electron-vue-template",
  "author": {
    "name": "Brayozin",
    "url": "https://github.com/Brayozin"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "1.47.1",
    "@types/node": "22.5.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.4.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "chokidar": "^3.5.3",
    "daisyui": "^4.12.10",
    "electron": "^27.1.0",
    "electron-builder": "^24.2.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.45",
    "postcss-loader": "^8.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.11",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.8",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "daisyui": "^4.12.10",
    "playwright": "^1.47.1",
    "playwright-chromium": "^1.47.1",
    "sqlite3": "5.1.6",
    "vite": "^2.9.18",
    "vue": "3.3.8",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.13",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0"
  }
}

build.js
const Path = require('path');
const Chalk = require('chalk');
const FileSystem = require('fs');
const Vite = require('vite');
const compileTs = require('./private/tsc');

function buildRenderer() {
    return Vite.build({
        configFile: Path.join(__dirname, '..', 'vite.config.js'),
        base: './',
        mode: 'production'
    });
}


console.log(Chalk.blueBright('Transpiling renderer & main...'));
console.log(Chalk.blueBright('PATH: ', Path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build')));
function buildMain() {
    const mainPath = Path.join(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'main');
    return compileTs(mainPath);
}


function copyScrapperBrowser() {
  const srcPath = Path.join(
    __dirname,
    "..",
    "src",
    "main",
    "scrapper",
    "browser"
  );
  const destPath = Path.join(
    __dirname,
    "..",
    "dist",
    "scrapper",
    "browser"
  );
  FileSystem.mkdirSync(destPath, { recursive: true });
  FileSystem.cpSync(srcPath, destPath, { recursive: true });
}

function copyMainJs() {
  const srcPath = Path.join(__dirname, "..", "src", "main", "main.js");
  const destPath = Path.join(__dirname, "..", "dist", "main", "main.js");
  FileSystem.mkdirSync(Path.dirname(destPath), { recursive: true });
  FileSystem.copyFileSync(srcPath, destPath);
}


FileSystem.rmSync(Path.join(__dirname, "..", "build"), {
  recursive: true,
  force: true,
});

console.log(Chalk.blueBright("Transpiling renderer & main..."));
console.log(Chalk.blueBright("PATH: ", Path.join(__dirname, "..", "build")));

FileSystem.rmSync(Path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build'), {
    recursive: true,
    force: true,
})

console.log(Chalk.blueBright('Transpiling renderer & main...'));

Promise.allSettled([
    buildRenderer(),
    buildMain(),
]).then(() => {
    copyScrapperBrowser();
        // copyMainJs();

    console.log(Chalk.greenBright('Renderer & main successfully transpiled! (ready to be built with electron-builder)'));
});


ConfigBrowser src/main/scrapper/configBrowser.js
import { chromium } from "playwright";
import { login } from "./login.js";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
const { app } = require("electron");

export async function configBrowser() {
  const contextFilePath = "browserContext.json";
  let context;
  let page;

      const executablePath = path.join(
        appPath,
        "scrapper",
        "browser",
        "chrome",
        "chrome"
      );

  let actualDir = __dirname;
  console.log("executablePath====================================");
  console.log(executablePath);
  console.log("====================================executablePath");
  const browser = await chromium.launch({
    headless: false,
    devtools: true,
    args: [
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--no-devtools",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--mute-audio",
    ],
    executablePath: executablePath,
    // executablePath: "./browser/chrome/chrome", // src/main/scrapper/browser/chrome/chrome
    timeout: 60000, // Increase timeout to 60 seconds
  });

  if (fs.existsSync(contextFilePath)) {
    console.log("oi1");
    const contextData = fs.readFileSync(contextFilePath, "utf8");
    context = await browser.newContext({
      storageState: JSON.parse(contextData),
    });
...

